# Can someone explain this markers?

Tags: css

I am looking at a few css docs and I see many people use markup like this `#nav > ul > li` when styling their lists. I am not too familiar with how that works and was wondering if someone could explain what it is called to use carrots when styling list items, so I can find some info online.

I am used to doing it more like `#nav ul` or `#nav li`

Thank you.

Comment: Look for CSS selectors directly. There aren't so many of them.

Comment: Here is a list of selectors and what they mean http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html

Comment: You need to learn CSS.

Comment: I actually know CSS a decent bit. I don't pretend to be a pro, but that's why I am asking the nomenclature, so I can improve my skills. Sorry I offend you with mu ignorance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `>` selector will select elements that are a direct child of the former.

Example:

`ul > li > a` and `ul a` will BOTH select the `a` below, however `ul > a` will **not** as it is not a **direct** child.

```
<ul>
   <li>
        <a>Hello World</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

**EDIT**: as others have said in comments, read more about all the css selectors here:  http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html